# designing or customizing audio pieces on a website using css and html

Tags: html, css, audio, customization

I wanted to customize my audio tag (output) by creating a transparent stream of audio or a beep like in google meet.

The transparent stream should be on the audio piece but under the text of it. you can find many streams in professional video editors like premier pro on the timeline.

if this is not possible then is there a professional way to customize the audio piece when the visitor of the website clicks on it

....

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds less like a problem and more like a task.

Comment: it is a problem, i tried many ways such as the one in the problem (stream)  which did not work. so i decided to ask.